# How to use properly ng-change on angularjs dropdown element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have this dropdownlist in my template:

```
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <select class="form-control" 
                    data-ng-options="o.name for o in list.itemsStatus" 
                    data-ng-model="list.currentItemsStatus"
                    ng-change="list.getItems(o.id)">   
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is how is defined itemsStatus in controller:

```
  this.itemsStatus = [{ name: "all", id: 1 }, { name: "new", id: 2 }, { name: "toUpdate", id: 3 }];
```

when new item is selected I fire this function:

```
    function getItems(status) {
        switch (status) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
```

But passed parameter- `status` is always undefined.

How can I pass to getItems() event the selected item as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-change` event can't pass `ng-options` current item as value.

You already do have selected value inside your `ng-model`, so you can pass your model which already has `o`(current selected value)

```
ng-change="list.getItems(list.currentItemsStatus.id)"
```